# Polling request with Coroutines Channels

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need to do a polling in an API every 20 seconds. When I leave the screen the polling should stop.

My problem is that I tried using Coroutines Channels and it is only calling it once. I'm not sure how to make it call multiple times.

In the RemoteDataSource class I have the following logic:

```
override suspend fun fetchInfo(id: String): Channel<Result<MyModel, ResultError>> {
        val channel = Channel<Result<MyModel, ResultError>>()
        GlobalScope.launch { sendId(channel, id, 20000) }
        return channel
}

suspend fun sendId(channel: SendChannel<Result<MyModel, ResultError>>, id: String, time: Long) {
            while (true) {
                channel.send(
                    safeApiCall {
                        api.fetchInfo(id)
                    }.mapSuccess { infoResponse ->
                        mapper.mapFrom(infoResponse)
                    }
                )
                delay(time)
            }
}

override suspend fun cancelFetchInfo() {
        coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
}
```

In this class I have another API call that works fine:

```
override suspend fun createInfo(createInfo: CreateInfoModel): Result<MyModel, ResultError> =
    safeApiCall {
        api.createInfo(createInfo)
    }.mapSuccess { infoResponse ->
        mapper.mapFrom(infoResponse)
    }
```

The safeApiCall is:

```
suspend fun <T> safeApiCall(
    dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
    apiCall: suspend () -> T
): Result<T, ResultError.NetworkError> {
    return withContext(dispatcher) {
        try {
            Result.Success(apiCall())
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The function fetchInfo() is called when the activity starts and cancelFetchInfo() should be called when the activity is paused.

In my viewModel I'm doing this

```
fun fetchInfo() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val channel = fetchInfo("1")
        channel.receive()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want this request to be called periodically until your activity is finished?

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar yes, or unit I click something that will call cancelFetchInfo()

Comment: This not the way of it. you are way of completely wrong. your function should return a `Flow` or the `Channel` itself and its the activity role to receive from that channel. Also, you should call that `while (true)` in a `launch` to do it nonblocking.